# A problem about diffeomorphism of two components of the boundary of a manifold.

Tags: smooth-manifolds, morse-theory, manifolds-with-boundary, cobordism

My geometry professor said that the following statement is true:
Let $M$ be a compact smooth manifold such that $\partial M = M_0 \cup M_1$. Suppose that there exist a smooth function $f:M \to \mathbb R$ such that $f^{-1}(i) = M_i$ for $i=0,1$. If the derivative of the function $f$ is not null at every point of $M$ then $M_0$ and $M_1$ are diffeomorphic.

I have two questions:

1) Is this result really true?    I didn't find any reference where it's stated.

2) If it's true, how to i prove it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Silly example: take the disjoint union of the closed unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and a solid torus, and let $f$ be radius squared $-1$ on the unit ball and constantly $1$ on the solid torus. Did I misunderstand the statement or perhaps some small changes could fix the statement? This looks like a result in Morse theory, but I'm not really familiar with the topic...

Comment: @Qidi Perhaps one should assume M to be connected.

Comment: Well, but in your example the derivative is zero on the torus.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you meant $\neg$(null everywhere). How about a pair of pants(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_of_pants_(mathematics)) embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$, arranged so that the boundaries are at height $0$ and $1$ respectively, with $f$ being the height function? Also to annoy you with more silly examples we could take e.g. $M_0$ to be $\emptyset$ and $M$ some manifold with non-empty boundary. Then we just arrange so that $0$ is not in the image of $f$.

Comment: In the picture of wiki, In the pants case, there is a point where the derivative of the height is zero. It's in the middle of the picture where the legs join.

Comment: I agree the not null everywhere was a little bit unclear, i changed it. Thanks.

Comment: I think what you described is a cobordism, and $f$ is a Morse function since it has no critical points. I searched around and found this article (http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/surgery/exoticspheres.pdf) that states "Prop 3.1: a cobordism with Morse number zero is a product cobordism", I understand this as if $\exists f\colon M\to \mathbb{R}$ with no critical points then $M\cong M_0 \times [0,1]$. Maybe you could add the tags "Morse theory" and "cobordism" so people who understand the topic more could give a better answer for your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A statement that you can adapt to your situation is:

Theorem: Let $f:M\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a Morse function on a smooth manifold. Assume that $a<b$ are given such that  $f^{-1}([a,b])$ is compact and that there are no critical values $c$ with $a\leq c\leq  b$. Then $f^{-1}(a)$ and $f^{-1}(b)$ are diffeomorphic.

The keyword is Morse theory. This is the first thing (varying conditions like compactness) one proves in this direction. A standard and good reference is Milnor's aptly named Morse theory.